# Authentication against Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, directoryservices

I am just having a user name and not having any password. I just want to check if this user name exist in [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory). How do I go about it?

Comment: You should always add the language to the tags list ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 3.5, you can use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` features. Your code would look something like:

```
// create a "principal context" - e.g. your domain (could be machine, too)
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "username");

bool userExists = (user != null);
```

That should do the trick ;-)

For more details on S.DS.AM, see this excellent MSDN article:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string strDomain = DOMAINNAME;
string strUserId = USERNAME;

string strPath = "LDAP://DC=" + strDomain.Trim() + ",DC=com";

DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(strPath);
DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);

deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" + strUserId.Trim() + "))";

SearchResult results = deSearch.FindOne();
if ((results == null))
{
    //No User Found
}
else
{
   //User Found
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the objectCategory=person instead of objectClass. ObjectCategory is single-valued and indexed, while objectClass is not --> using objectCategory makes your AD query faster

Comment: @marc_s: One can use either both *objectCategory* and *objectClass* or *objectClass* only as using *objectCategory* only within the filter doesn't work in .NET.

Comment: You should not use this method, as it also attempts to *read* values in Active Directory, rather than check authentication. You can have valid credentials but the code will fail because you don't have permission to look up users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class `DirectoryEntry` for such tasks. See the `Exists`-method here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.exists.aspx